# Allow access to myself and server for cron job

Tags: php, apache

I've done the following for a page that needs to be loaded every few minutes.
It's working for what I want to do but it's not very secure if I'm not mistaken. (Would be easy to spoof my ip address?)

```
   if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] != 'my_ip' AND $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] != $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]) {
            die();  
    }
```

What's a better way to do this?